# IdentityServer4 - modify token at consent

Tags: identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 and I have implemented implicit flow using the demo UI. My client is using the consent screen and I have a case where I need to add some additional parameters to the token after consent. In consent controller POST action:

1. Is there a way to get the current token? I see that there is a state parameter sent to the controller and passed around with each call. Since the token is created after login, I'm guessing IS4 is using this state to keep the token somewhere in memory. Is there a way for me to retrieve it?
2. How can I modify the token and add additional claims to it at the consent POST action?

Answer (score 0):

In identity server 4 we have a profile service to modify token claims

```
services.AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
```